# Updating a Repeater but not redrawing entire repeater, just adding new items

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I could do this..

I'm making a video player with youtube. I want to loading the new videos in from the database without doing a post back. I've done it with a repeater and a update panel but when it updates the entire repeater is redrawn and the video starts again.. I want it to be able to update on the run without resetting the video.

How can do such functionality? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. You can't do this with a server control and not run into the refresh problem. It's hard to be more specific without seeing your markup and knowing your page layout.

You could likely append new items through jQuery/AJAX, but if you have separated the YouTube video section from the list of new videos, it'd probably be easier to re-load the entire list of videos from another page. I'm not familiar with the YouTube video player and how you interact with the object on a webpage, so I could be way off-base here.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using a repeater only matters when the page is first being built. Once it is rendered into HTML and the YouTube video is playing you obviously do not want to postback to get fresh information.

Instead of using an UpdatePanel, you should look in the direction of an AJAX call to get fresh information and binding the results on the client-side.

Let me know if this interests you and i'll be happy to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

With databound controls the only thing you can do is append to the datasource. There is no way to add items directly to a datbound control.